# Numpy: equivalent of numpy.roll but only for data visualisation

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

**Is there a way to perform a roll on an array, but instead of having a copy of the data having just a different visualisation of it?**

An example might clarify: given `b` a rolled version of `a`...

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 3))
>>> a
array([[6, 7, 4],
       [5, 4, 8],
       [1, 3, 4]])
>>> b = np.roll(a, 1, axis=0)
>>> b
array([[1, 3, 4],
       [6, 7, 4],
       [5, 4, 8]])
```

...if I perform an assignment on array `b`...

```
>>> b[2,2] = 99
>>> b
array([[ 1,  3,  4],
       [ 6,  7,  4],
       [ 5,  4, 99]])
```

...the content of `a` won't change...

```
>>> a
array([[6, 7, 4],
       [5, 4, 8],
       [1, 3, 4]])
```

...contrarily, I would like to have:

```
>>> a
array([[6, 7, 4],
       [5, 4, 99],    # observe as `8` has been changed here too!
       [1, 3, 4]])
```

Thanks in advance for your time and expertise!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible, sorry. The rolled array cannot be described by a different set of [strides](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html), which would be necessary for a NumPy view to work.